# Acumos design studio loading forever

Tags: acumos

On my local Acumos instance, which I installed using the oneclick install, I can successfully onboard models, but the design studio loads forever when try to use it. All docker containers are up and running and I see no related errors neither in the logfiles nor in the browser javascript console. It's the same for Chrome or Firefox. 
This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This failure to start happens on an instance with no models, or on an instance where you have on-boarded some models? At one time there was a bug that DSCE would not start if the database was empty.  https://jira.acumos.org/browse/ACUMOS-1897

Comment: I have one model onboarded and published to company marketplace..

Comment: You have models, hmm.  Also please post the version as shown in the footer of the portal-mktpl page.

Comment: The version is 1.16.2

Answer (score 0):

I have not see a case in which the Design Studio failed to present its UI in the Portal frame. But we can get to the bottom of this for you. Some questions:

1) Did you deploy using docker or kubernetes

2) What is the Design Studio image version defined in acumos-env.sh (DESIGNSTUDIO_IMAGE)

3) When did you clone the system-integration repo

4) If you know how to use the web debugging tools in your browser, check what request is being sent that is not being responded to. A typical successful response is attached as a picture, captured using chrome's Developer Tools option (Network tab).

[image: Design Studio tab request]

Comment: 1) I deployed using docker
2) design studio image1.40.2
3) I cloned today

Comment: Do you need more information? Are you able to reproduce it? Or is it some kind of personal issue in my environment?